# Is it possible to precalculate the height of text to be printed in renpy?

Tags: python, renpy

Renpy uses a lot of python and custom made code, in order to show text that is displayed on screen using the `say statement`.

After running into some troubles with the `nvl mode` within renpy, I found it necessary to know how many lines are going to be displayed on screen (taking into account the font size, naturally and the size of the text window).

**So my question**:

As I didn't find anything in the documentation in regards to that, I'm wondering if there is any command or other possibility to precalculate the height of a text that is to be displayed?

Comment: There seems to be a virtual text size. Does this [commit](https://github.com/renpy/renpy/commit/7462532a77bc218ffe369990a28f86f1ee173599) help you in any way?

Comment: @rocksteady would that then be used by calling get_virtual_layout?

Comment: I think so. You can then use `.width` or `.height` on that. As far as I understand, it is used to compute the text size before printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_virtual_layout()` is part of `class Text` in `text.py`.

I copied this from `text.py`:

```
# Find the virtual-resolution layout.
virtual_layout = self.get_virtual_layout()
# The laid-out size of this Text.
vw, vh = virtual_layout.size
```

This looks promising, I think.

With the virtual text size (width, height) you could possibly calculate the lines of text by using the text window size (width, height).

```
pseudo code:
lines = int(vw/text_window.width)
#the text height would then be
text_height_needed = int(lines*vh)
# does it fit in completely
complete_text_in_window = text_window.height >= text_height_needed
# visible lines
visible_lines = int(text_window.height/vh)
```

Also, it is worth to take a deeper look at `text.py`(e.g. `def render(self, width, height, st, at)`), in order to get to know the use of `virtual_layout`.

I hope it helps somehow.

**Update**:

`def render(...)` initializes the virtual layouts, so `get_virtual_layout()` is not None anymore, but represents an instance of `Layout()` with scaled width and height.

Comment: get_virtual_layout alone is not enough (rv which is returned is always none if you  use this:  $x = Text("Test text1")     $rv= x.get_virtual_layout()
    $vw, vh = rv.size

Comment: See `def render(...)`. It creates the initial layout.

Comment: Yepp steps are: $x=Text("blah")  #    $x.render(300,300,0,0)
#    $rv= x.get_virtual_layout()
#    $vw, vh = rv.size

Comment: And still `None` as output?

Comment: Nope that repaired it. $x.render in essence set the array element that get_virtual_layout tries to retrieve

Comment: Yeah :) Congratulations!